# How can I track which lat/lon values were projected with D3 adaptive resampling?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using a `d3.geoOrthographic` projection to draw great circle arcs between cities using a `d3.geoPath`:

```
path({
    type: "LineString",
    coordinates: [origin, destination],
    precision: 1
})
```

Following Mike Bostock's [example here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3795544) I can capture the projected x,y values for the resampled points, but I'd like to capture the corresponding sequence of lat/lon values, prior to projection.  I've tried wrapping my original `projection` to intercept the `point` method, but it only gets called for the start and end of the line, not the intermediate points.  I think the resampling is buried somewhere deeper in the stream.   Is there some clever way I can capture the intermediate points getting generated in D3's [resampleLine](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/src/projection/resample.js#L23)?

Actually the thing I'm really looking for is a sequence of 'interpolator' offsets along the (untransformed) great arc, ranging from 0 at the start to 1 at the end, so that I can vary the stroke color uniformly, as a geo version of [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057).   As a fallback I could use geoInterpolate directly and draw "too many" points at regular intervals, but it seemed nicer to go use the adaptive machinery.